# I want Django orm to find difference in days between current date and a date time field from dB table

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

The my SQL query shown in the below.
I want Django orm for Below query.

```
select 
greatest((30-ifnull(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),disabled_on),0)),0) AS unblock_days
from tbl_users;
```

Django Model:

```
Class Users(models.Model):
    User_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    disabled_on = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null 
    = True).
```

Note:  `'disabled_on'  datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you should add your djnago model to the question, don't put it as comment, nut edit your question.

Comment: I included my model Bear Brown